A question of conditional probability on choosing elements from a set
I face the following problem in probability:

In a group of 90 students, 54 students do service with young children and 47 students do service with elderly people. 15 students do service with both young children and elderly people. Three students are selected at random from the group. Find the probability that all three students do service with young children, given that at least one student does service with young children.

My attempts:

This is a conditional probability problem.

Let A be the event: selecting randomly three students in 90 students and they all do service with young children.

Let B be the event: at least one of them does service with young children.

I have to calculate $P(A|B)$ so, I have to calculate $P(A\cap B)$ and $P(B)$.

To calculate $P(B)$, I calculate the probability that no student does service with children.
The probability that a randomly chosen student doesn't work with children is $\dfrac{36}{90}=\dfrac{2}{5}$ so, the probability that three randomly chosen students is $\left(\dfrac{2}{5}\right)^3$ then $P(B) = 1-\left(\dfrac{2}{5}\right)^3=\dfrac{117}{125}$


My question is:

Is my $P(B)$ correct? If not, then why is it wrong? Is that the choice of students are not independent?

What is $P(A\cap B)$? Is it $P(A)$ since clearly the set of three students doing service with young children is a subset of the set of three students that at least one of them work with young children?


Please help me.
Thanks

I would suggest not defining $A$ and $B$ as you have; they just complicate the problem.  Also, the selection of students is not independent, since the probability that the three students all work with children is $\frac{36}{90}\times \frac{35}{89}\times \frac{34}{88} \neq \left(\frac 25\right)^3$. Do you see why?

You had found out that $36$ people don't serve children
Often it is simpler to use the $\texttt{reduced sample space}$ for computing conditional probability,
Thus P($3$ serve children | $>0$ serve children) $ =\dfrac{\binom{54}3}{\binom{90}3 - \binom{36}3} =\dfrac{689}{3065}$
